# changeEvent never called with WindowStateChange

Tags: c++, qt, qt5

I am trying to listen for `WindowStateChangeEvent`s in Qt. When I have the following implementation, it never reaches `state`.

```
void
FooWidget::changeEvent(QEvent* e) {
    BaseWidget::changeEvent(e);

    if (e->type() != QEvent::WindowStateChange)
        return;

    auto state = static_cast<QWindowStateChangeEvent*>(e);
```

Setting a breakpoint on the `if` it only gets the following types of events:

```
QEvent::StyleChange
QEvent::ParentChange
QEvent::LocaleChange
```

Is there any additional step needed to get the Window events reported?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So seems like `WindowStateChangeEvent` is not propagated to children.

So you can use the above code in a `QFooWindow`.
Sadly when then trying to `sendEvent` further to all children, it crashes.